# How to count elements in xml tag

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

i have a small problem with my script and i'm stuck... I need to count elements in my xml main tags, independently of their names. Can you tell me how to do this?

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"../amica_programator/data/content_data.xml",
    dataType:"xml",
    success: function(xml) {
            var class_main_content = $('.main_content ul').attr('class');
            var xml_element_name = $(xml).find(class_main_content)[0].nodeName.toLowerCase();
            if ((class_main_content) == xml_element_name){
                var n_elements = $(xml).find(xml_element_name).find("element").size();
                alert(n_elements);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your XML data is not a `XMLDocument` first you should parse it with [`$.parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/). After that you can use simple selectors to find count of elements. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/AHzAr/1/);

```
var xml = '<root><tag_01><element></element><element></element><element></element></tag_01><tag_02><element></element><element></element></tag_02></root>',
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml)
    $xml = $(xmlDoc),
    tagName01 = 'tag01',
    tagName02 = 'tag02';
alert('total <element> count: ' + $xml.find('element').size());
alert('total <tag_01 > element> count: ' + $xml.find(tagName01 + ' > element').size());
alert('total <tag_02 > element> count: ' + $xml.find(tagName02 + ' > element').size());
```

ps: I have to add `<root>` to make XML valid.

Comment: ok, but i need to count elements in choose tag, wich i get comparing them with some list class from html... my code below

Comment: I gave you the basics, the rest is up to you now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('*') 
      .filter(function() { 
          return this.nodeName.toLowerCase().match(/tag_*/); 
      }).each(function(){
          alert($(this).find('element').size());
      });
```

Try out this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnzuK/)